# EF Core - Missing related entity in class despite foreign key after running Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

In a SQL Server database, I have two almost identical tables `TBL_1` and `TBL_2`.
Here are the create scripts for both tables:

TBL_1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [value_type_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__TBL_1__param__40F9A68C]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_1_description]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [description]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TBL_1_TBL_value_types] FOREIGN KEY([value_type_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ([value_type_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TBL_1_TBL_value_types]
GO
```

TBL_2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [value_type_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_2_name]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TBL_2_TBL_value_types] FOREIGN KEY([value_type_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ([value_type_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TBL_2_TBL_value_types]
GO
```

After executing Scaffold-DbContext, the following classes were generated for these two tables:

```
public partial class Tbl2
{
    public Tbl2()
    {
        Tbl2Translations = new HashSet<Tbl2Translation>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tbl2Translation> Tbl2Translations { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tbl1
{
    public Tbl1()
    {
        Tbl1Translations = new HashSet<Tbl1Translation>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual TblValueTypeDefinition ValueType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tbl1Translation> Tbl1Translations { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, a related `ValueType` is generated for `Tbl1`, but not for `Tbl2`. I've already compared the tables in the database but I cannot find any obvious reason for why the related `ValueType` is missing in `Tbl2`. This is very frustrating because I have no starting point for debugging this issue so it basically feels like searching for a needle in a haystack. Here is the generated `TblValueTypeDefinition` class:

```
public partial class TblValueTypeDefinition
{
    public TblValueTypeDefinition()
    {
        Tbl2s = new HashSet<Tbl2>();
    }

    public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tbl2> Tbl2s { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the create script for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition](
    [value_type_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [unit] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_Value_Type_Definition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [value_type_ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [unit]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [type]
GO
```

What could be the reason why the related entity is missing in one of the tables?

Comment: Can you also provide the TblValueTypeDefinition class and its associated database table structure? If you are really worried about using the associated parent object through code, you can directly add the relationship through code. If it is about Scaffold-Dbcontext, then yes, it does have its own limitations in terms of how it perceives SQL to C# class. So, we might need to dig in deeper on the related table schema as well.

Comment: @sabharikarthik I added the class and the create script to my question. I'd like to avoid modifying the generated code in any way because I'd have to repeat doing this every single time `Scaffold-DbContext` is executed again after database changes.

Comment: From TblValueTypeDefinition Class, I could see the references for Tbl2s but not the other way around. So, it is worth looking at the DbContext -> OnConfiguring function to see if the SQL schema -> EF Model conversion is proper. Also, it is worth trying the CodeFirst approach if you have the scope to try out.

Comment: I wonder what we can do about it. It's clearly something in the scaffolding code. Since generated code nearly always requires customization I wouldn't worry about it too much. Also, there are other, better re-engineering tools.

Comment: @GertArnold Which other tool would you recommend instead? From my experience, I've used `Scaffold-DbContext` in about half a dozen projects so far and I never ever had to customize the generated code afterwards, so I don't really understand your argument. If the foreign keys are identical for multiple tables, I think it makes sense to expect to get the same navigation properties in the generated classes.

Comment: Sure, it makes sense, but if it's in the scaffolding code we can't do anything about it and you may consider reporting a bug.  Try [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools).

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks! Next time I have the chance, I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Could I ask you to maybe check if the FK is actually created on the Tbl2? 
Scaffolding code, should not be able to generate the proper class for one table and then not the other, this seems ... impossible. I would check that in terms of the column "value_type_id" you dig and find ANYTHING that isn't the same for both tables, and then try scaffolding again.

I am assuming there is a spelling mistake, either at the field level, og something similar, that is causing the scaffolding to not recognize the relation to TBL_value_type_definition, for TBL2

Comment: @MortenBork Exactly! I have already compared the CREATE scripts for both tables line by line and I cannot find a single difference anywhere. Both tables have the FK defined. It looks exactly the same so I can't wrap my head around how EF Core generates the navigation property for one table but not for the other table. Since I asked this question, I even found another table with the exact same problem for the same column. The FK also looks exactly the same in that table but the navigation property does not get generated.

Comment: You can check if proper relations are there after you create the tables in Database diagrams in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

**Table 1** has an error in table name  `REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_value_types]` instead of `REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition]`

[image: error]

**Table2** has the same error (Table name). `REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_value_types]` instead of REFERENCES `[dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition]`

> The tables are created but the references are broken. No foreign keys are created.
> [image: diagram 1]

**Fixed code - Sql script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition](
    [value_type_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [unit] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [type] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_Value_Type_Definition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [value_type_ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [unit]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ADD  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [type]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [value_type_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__TBL_1__param__40F9A68C]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_1_description]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [description]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TBL_1_TBL_value_types] FOREIGN KEY([value_type_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ([value_type_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TBL_1_TBL_value_types]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [value_type_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_2_name]  DEFAULT ('-') FOR [name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [TBL_2_TBL_value_types] FOREIGN KEY([value_type_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ([value_type_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [TBL_2_TBL_value_types]
GO
```

> [image: diagram ok]

**Scaffold-DbContext** from **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** nuget package

`Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=SO1;User ID=sa;Password=100;Encrypt=False" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

## GeneratedCode

**SO1Context.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EfCoreMissingRelated
{
    public partial class SO1Context : DbContext
    {
        public SO1Context()
        {
        }

        public SO1Context(DbContextOptions<SO1Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Tbl1> Tbl1s { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual DbSet<Tbl2> Tbl2s { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual DbSet<TblValueTypeDefinition> TblValueTypeDefinitions { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=SO1;User ID=sa;Password=100;Encrypt=False");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tbl1>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TBL_1");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                    .HasMaxLength(150)
                    .HasColumnName("description")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .HasColumnName("name")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");

                entity.Property(e => e.ValueTypeId).HasColumnName("value_type_ID");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.ValueType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Tbl1s)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ValueTypeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("TBL_1_TBL_value_types");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tbl2>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TBL_2");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .HasColumnName("name")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");

                entity.Property(e => e.ValueTypeId).HasColumnName("value_type_ID");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.ValueType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Tbl2s)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ValueTypeId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("TBL_2_TBL_value_types");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TblValueTypeDefinition>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ValueTypeId);

                entity.ToTable("TBL_Value_Type_Definition");

                entity.Property(e => e.ValueTypeId).HasColumnName("value_type_ID");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("name")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");

                entity.Property(e => e.Type)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .HasColumnName("type")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");

                entity.Property(e => e.Unit)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .HasColumnName("unit")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("('-')");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Tbl1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCoreMissingRelated
{
    public partial class Tbl1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual TblValueTypeDefinition ValueType { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

**Tbl2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCoreMissingRelated
{
    public partial class Tbl2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual TblValueTypeDefinition ValueType { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

**TblValueTypeDefinition.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCoreMissingRelated
{
    public partial class TblValueTypeDefinition
    {
        public TblValueTypeDefinition()
        {
            Tbl1s = new HashSet<Tbl1>();
            Tbl2s = new HashSet<Tbl2>();
        }

        public int ValueTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Unit { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Type { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<Tbl1> Tbl1s { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tbl2> Tbl2s { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a typo in my question. The actual CREATE scripts contain `REFERENCES [dbo].[TBL_Value_Type_Definition] ([value_type_ID])`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Using your new fixed sql scripts, the result is the same generated code in my answer.  `public virtual TblValueTypeDefinition ValueType { get; set; } = null!;` is present in both classes `Tbl1` and `Tbl2`.

Comment: @Jamo That's exactly what I would expect, but it's not the case when I run `Scaffold-DbContext` in my environment. I've actually had a similar problem before in another SO question where the error I got could not be reproduced by anyone else with the code from my question. I don't know what to do at this point. If this is some weird environment- or version-specific issue then I guess it's probably near impossible for you or anyone else to help me out here. I'm going to award you the bounty anyway for your efforts.